# Checking if an object is an int or int-like in Python C API

Tags: python, python-c-api

Is there a an operation similar to [`PyInt_Check`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_Check)/[`PyLong_Check`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_Check) that takes into account whether or not the type has an `__int__` method?

The closest workaround I have been able to find so far is

```
int check_int(PyObject *obj)
{
    long lng;
    int over;

    lng = PyLong_AsLongAndOverflow(obj, &over);
    if(lng == -1 && over == 0 && PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyErr_Clear();
#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION <= 2
        lng = PyInt_AsLong(obj);
        if(lng == -1L && PyErr_Occurred()) {
            PyErr_Clear();
            return 0;
        }
#else
        return 0;
#endif
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The problem here is that I am effectively doing something like

```
def isint(obj):
    try:
        int(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

However, this being C, I would prefer to do something like

```
def isint(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, int) or hasattr(type(obj), '__int__')
```

I would expect such a check to already exist because [`PyInt_AsLong`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_AsLong) and [`PyLong_AsLongAndOverflow`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsLongAndOverflow) already perform it. I just want to be able to know if an object might be an integer without getting the integer value at all.

That being said, I can see the point of actually getting the value, since `hasattr(type(obj), '__int__')` does not actually guarantee that the object can be reasonably used as an integer: e.g., if the attribute is not a function or just raises an error. In that case "no" may be a valid answer.

Comment: Are you sure you want `__int__` and not `__index__`?

Comment: @user2357112. Absolutely. In case you are wondering why, I am adding it to [numpy PR#10820](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/10820)

Comment: @user2357112. That being said, if you know something relevant about `__index__`, please share.

Comment: [`PyIndex_Check`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyIndex_Check) checks for an `__index__` method.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately that is not what I want. I'm fixing up my C code BTW. It's a mess ATM

Comment: @user2357112. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to a function for that is [`PyNumber_Long`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Long), or [`PyNumber_Int`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Int) on Python 2. Both of these functions actually perform the conversion. They will also consider methods like `__trunc__`, and convert strings to ints, just like calling `int` from Python-level code.

If you want to check for the presence of an `__int__` conversion method, you can look for the corresponding slot directly:

```
if (o->ob_type->tp_as_number and o->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_int) {
    do_whatever();
}
```

Comment: As I noted in the end of my question, I am perfectly fine to do the conversion, I just didn't want to do it myself. It is also very nice that both functions eat up the exception. I will still have to add the `#if`, but that is a small price to pay.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Perhaps that is not what I want after all. Excellent answer and food for thought.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I'm not sure about the exception part; the docs don't mention raising an exception, but the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/abstract.c#L1314) seems to produce an exception for invalid input.

Comment: That is to be expected since `int` raises a `TypeError` if you try funny stuff.